# Creating a dynamic zip of a bunch of URLs on the fly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.5

I am trying to create a zip file of any size on the fly. The source of the zip archive is a bunch of URLs and could be potentially large (500 4MB JPGs in the list). I want to be able to do everything inside the request and have the download start right away and have the zip created and streamed as it is built. It should not have to reside in memory or on disk on the server.

The closest I have come is this:
Note: urls is a keyvaluepair of URLs to the file names as they should exist in the created zip

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=DyanmicZipFile.zip");

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> fileNamePair in urls)
        {
            var zipEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileNamePair.Key);

            using (var entryStream = zipEntry.Open())
                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    wc.OpenRead(GetUrlForEntryName(fileNamePair.Key)).CopyTo(entryStream);

                //this doesn't work either
                //using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
                //  using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                //      streamWriter.Write(wc.OpenRead(GetUrlForEntryName(fileNamePair.Key)));
        }
    }

    memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

This code gives me a zip file, but each JPG file inside the zip is just a text file that says "System.Net.ConnectStream" I have other attempts on this that do build a zip file with the proper files inside, but you can tell by the delay at the beginning that the server is completely building the zip in memory and then blasting it down at the end. It doesn't respond at all when the file count gets near 50. The part in comments gives me the same result I have tried Ionic.Zip as well.

This is .NET 4.5 on IIS8. I am building with VS2013 and trying to run this on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: The `StreamWriter` version won't work because the call to `streamWriter.Write` ends up calling `ToString()` on the client stream, which resolves to `Object.ToString()`, and just writes the class name. I can't really say why the `CopyTo` version doesn't work. Are you sure that creates the same zip file as the `StreamWriter` version?

Comment: If I move the `memoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)` part inside the `foreach` loop and add a `Response.Flush()` it seems to immediately begin streaming (first battle won), but the resulting zip file is much larger than it should be. My best guess is that they `WriteTo()` call is writing the entire stream so the zip file is (file1)+(file1+file2)+(file1+file2+file3) etc. `Write()` won't go directly to the `Response.Outputstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer my own question - here is the solution that works for me:

```
private void ProcessWithSharpZipLib()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream(Response.OutputStream);
    zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0); //0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression
    zipOutputStream.UseZip64 = ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.UseZip64.Off;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> fileNamePair in urls)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            using (Stream wcStream = wc.OpenRead(GetUrlForEntryName(fileNamePair.Key)))
            {
                ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry entry = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry(ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry.CleanName(fileNamePair.Key));

                zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

                int count = wcStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (count > 0)
                {
                    zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    count = wcStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Response.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    zipOutputStream.Close();

    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to create a zip file and have it stream while it's being created. This turns out to be very difficult.

You need to understand the [Zip file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29#Structure). In particular, notice that a local file entry has header fields that can't be updated (CRC, compressed and uncompressed file sizes) until the entire file has been compressed. So at minimum you'll have to buffer at least one entire file before sending it to the response stream.

So at best you could do something like:

```
open archive
for each file
    create entry
    write file to entry
    read entry raw data and send to the response output stream
```

The problem you'll run into is that there's no documented way (and no undocumented way that I'm aware of) to read the raw data. The only read method ends up decompressing the data and throwing away the headers.

There might be some other zip library available that can do what you need. I wouldn't suggest trying to do it with `ZipArchive`.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on a way to pile a bunch of files together and stream them like this? I don't need any actual compression since these are already compressed files that are going inside the collection. I just need to be able to make a single file from many and allow the user on the other end to open them with the usual OS-installed tools.

Comment: Another question - I know this is not the same zip library, but according to [this](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#-create-a-zip-as-a-browser-download-attachment-in-iis) you can do this with SharpZip. I haven't had a chance to try it yet.

Comment: @BradMurray: I have no knowledge of SharpZip's capabilities, or of any way to do what you're asking. You probably could write a .tar file, but to my knowledge there is no tar format reader installed with Windows (although it's possible to get one). I also don't know if the zip support built into Windows will handle the very large zip files you'll be generating (2 gigabytes, it looks like).

Comment: I tried the sample code that they have for SharpZip and it works like a champ - instant download start and no heavy resources on the server. I have the compression level set to zero since I am compressing JPGs and videos. I am not sure if it will work when the level is something larger. The zips that come down extract with OSX's decompresser, Windows' native one and 7zip with no complaints. The only downside is that the browser does not know the total size of the file which is to be expected since I can't supply that info to the response ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a way in the zip component you are using that allows for delayed addition of entries to the archive, ie. adding them after the zip.Save() is called. I am using IonicZip using the delayed technique, The code to download flickr albums looks like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsLoggedIn())
        Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");
    else
    {
        // this is dco album id, find out what photosetId it maps to
        string albumId = Request.Params["id"];
        Album album = findAlbum(new Guid(albumId));
        Flickr flickr = FlickrInstance();
        PhotosetPhotoCollection photos = flickr.PhotosetsGetPhotos(album.PhotosetId, PhotoSearchExtras.OriginalUrl | PhotoSearchExtras.Large2048Url | PhotoSearchExtras.Large1600Url);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.BufferOutput = false;

        // ascii only
        //string archiveName = album.Title + ".zip";
        string archiveName = "photos.zip";
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + archiveName);
        int picCount = 0;
        string picNamePref = album.PhotosetId.Substring(album.PhotosetId.Length - 6);
        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.None;
            zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.None;
            zip.ParallelDeflateThreshold = -1;
            _map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (Photo p in photos)
            {
                string pictureUrl = p.Large2048Url;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureUrl))
                    pictureUrl = p.Large1600Url;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureUrl))
                    pictureUrl = p.LargeUrl;

                string pictureName = picNamePref + "_" + (++picCount).ToString("000") + ".jpg";
                _map.Add(pictureName, pictureUrl);
                zip.AddEntry(pictureName, processPicture);
            }
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        Response.Close();
    }
}
private volatile Dictionary<string, string> _map;
protected void processPicture(string pictureName, Stream output)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(_map[pictureName]);
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream input = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            byte[] buf = new byte[8092];
            int len;
            while ( (len = input.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
                output.Write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        output.Flush();
    }
}
```

This ways the code in Page_Load gets to zip.Save() immediately, the download starts (the client is presented with the "Save As" box, and only  then the images are pulled from flickr.

Answer (score 0):

This code working fine but when I host my code on windows azure as cloud service it corrupts my zip file throwing message invalid file

```
private void ProcessWithSharpZipLib(){
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

    ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipOutputStream(Response.OutputStream);
    zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0); //0-9, 9 being the highest level of compression
    zipOutputStream.UseZip64 = ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.UseZip64.Off;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> fileNamePair in urls)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            using (Stream wcStream = wc.OpenRead(GetUrlForEntryName(fileNamePair.Key)))
            {
                ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry entry = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry(ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry.CleanName(fileNamePair.Key));

                zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);

                int count = wcStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                while (count > 0)
                {
                    zipOutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    count = wcStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Response.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    zipOutputStream.Close();

    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

This code is working fine on local machine but not after deployed on server. It corrupts my zip file if its large in size.